# How to add a mysql column value as the keyword of where query criteria？

Tags: mysql, sql

Example
have a table `A`,contains a column `method`,value like `>`,`<`,`IS NULL` ...

Other tables join `A`, query sql like `where b.age  (A.method) c.age`, by `A.method`'s value to  filter data.

Data of table `A`  can add、update,can't exhaust through 'case when'.

Comment: You need Dynamic SQL, operators can't be passed as strings.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use case when to handle specific methods. This is not a straight forward SQL. I am using case when, i know you mentioned case when cant be used, can you elaborate the reason with example.
Sample SQL,

```
where 
case 
when A.method ='>' AND b.age  > c.age then 1
when A.method ='<' AND b.age  < c.age then 1
when A.method is null AND b.age  is null and c.age is null then 1
...
else 0
end =1
```

Comment: Seems to be a clean solution.

Comment: Thanks,but table A can add  methods, can't use  case when

Comment: Tricky. But question is how many methods possible? if they are simple operations like you said (>,<, is null, =, <=,>=, <>) it can easily be handled using case when. But if its like a rule engine(e.g. 'b.age > c.age but <d.age and type ='S') then you need to write some script.